# Recurrence relationship of Hamiltonian backtracking

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, hamiltonian-path

I'm struggling to understand how to express the recurrence relation in terms of N of a backtracking algorithm to find out if a Hamiltonian path exists. Where N is the number of vectors.

After finding this I then need to find the worst case time complexity of the algorithm.

The algorithm is recursive, and works like so:

$
\text{Function isHamiltonian} (G , v)\\
~~\text{Input : }G := \{{V, E}\} \\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~where\ V\ :=\ \{{v_0, v_1, v_2, ..., v_n}\}\text { (set of vectors)}\\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~where\ E\ :=\ V\ \times\ V\ \text{(set of edges expressed as }(v_0, v_1)\  (v_0\ \text{goes to } v_1)\\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~v \in V\ \text{(starting vertex)}\\
\\
~~\text{Algorithm}\\
~~~~Let\ H:=\{{V', E}\}\ where\ V' = V\ \backslash\ v\\
~~~~\text{if}\ V' = \emptyset\\
~~~~~~~~\text{return true (There is a path)}\\
~~~~\text{for all}\ w \in V' : (v,\ w)\ \in E\\
~~~~~~~~\text{if isHamiltonian}(H,\ w)\text{ is true}\\
~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{return true}\\
~~~~\text{return false}
$

My problem is that I thought that the recurrence relation would vary with the number of edges, not just the number of vertices?

Also, I understand that the worst case is that the algorithm has to check every possible permutation $(n!)$, or here $(n-1!)$ (as the first vertex is preselected). So I thought that the worst case would be when there are the maximum number of permutations without having any possible paths (or a unique path). I just can't understand the conditions that reliably define a worst case graph. (Such as a strongly connected graph with the exception of one isolated point).

Any help you could give me would be very helpful. I've tried a lot of searching but most material deals with more complex algorithms than exhaustive search.